# 2 inputs divided by a slash

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

can someone help me achieve that 2 ínputs look like one divided by a slash
Also doing it with twitter-bootstrap

Idea : http://postimg.org/image/pcgbzj4s1/

What I got so far but there is divided also I think they should overlap(slash with inputs)

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="kerkim" id="input_main">
<i id="slash">/</i>
<div class="input-group">                           
<input id="address" class="form-control" type="text" >
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-ẃarning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/oroborus357/pen/doVKEP Here's the quick codepen I made for you, it shoud do what you need :)

```
<span class="first"><input type="text" /></span><input class="second" type="text" />

body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
input {
  background: white;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.first {
  position: relative;
}
.first:before {
  content: "/";
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: thanks but is there anyway doing it with bootstrap and overlay?

Comment: Ofcourse...Bootstrap is just a framework for faster and easier development of the repeating stuff..(A set of html/css elements)...And what do you mean by "overlay"?

Comment: i mean but one element over another the idea of background color!
make the inputs and put the slash over them

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean :S

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to it... here's two.

Given this html:

```
  <div class="container">
      <input type="text"> 
      <span class="slash"></span>
      <input type="text">
  </div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;  
}

.container input{
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.slash{
  transform: scale(3);
  position: absolute;
}
/* or.... */
.slash{
  width: 2px;
  height: 28px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}
```

A demo [here](http://jsbin.com/jopini/edit?html,css,output)